# Auto-create `belongs_to` record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, belongs-to

Similar questions have been asked before but I just can't figure this out.

So I have Model_A and Model_B. Model_B `belongs_to` Model_A. What I want to do is when I create Model_A is to automatically call the `create` method for Model B. Then a script takes over a generates a bunch of data for Model_B. I use `after_create` because this only has to happen once.

It needs done this way. If you wanna know the details feel free to ask...

So I got Model_A here. I just can't seem to get the right syntax in `create_model_b`. In the example I used I just get an error saying the method doesn't exist for Model_A.

```
class Model_A < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Model_B
  after_create :create_model_b

...

  def create_model_b
     #so I tried a bunch of stuff here but none of it worked
     #I need to create a Model_B which will contain the current Model_A id
     #ex. self.model_b.create(model_a_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

Model_B doesn't do anything special really:

```
class Model_B < ApplicationController
def create
    @model_b = Model_B.new(model_b_params)
    create_the_data

    respond_to do |format|
      if @model_b.save
           #redirect
      else
        #uh oh
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1.

```
class Model_A < ApplicationController

def create
  @model_a = ModelA.new(model_a_params)
  if @model_a.save
    ModelB.create(model_a_id: @model_a.id, .....)
    #create data for model B either here or with after_create (of model B)
    redirect_to somewhere_awesome_path
  else
     # rescue error
     render 'new'
  end
end
```

2.

```
class Model_A < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_model_b

   ...

  def create_model_b
    ModelB.create(model_a_id: id)
  end
end
```

Comment: So I tried both methods and neither work. It's as if the `create` method isn't actually being called (although I don't get any errors about it not existing). When I stepped through the code it definitely never goes to that method. Hmm... @miler350

Comment: Yes. @miler350 Also...it seems like `Model_B` is being created too. But when I go to download any of the files they're blank. Even just printing out the fields results in nothing even though, for now, I explicitly set them to something like "TEST FIELD".

Comment: Also, is it a possibility  `Model_B` being implicitly generated in some weird way? I can definitely find the `Model_B` I want by `Model_A.id` and print the memory reference.

Comment: So I got it working. Not the way it should work though. I create `Model_B` as in the second way you present. That model is returned and I store it in `model_b_var`. Then I `model_b_var.create_files`, which I just put in that model for this purpose, and save. I can download the files just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your Model A contains half of an association: `belongs_to :Model_B`

Your Model B is missing its association to Model A.

Depending on the relationship you set up, you can complete the association with a `has_one :Model_A`, or `has_many :Model_A`, for example.

Here's [Active Record documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for reference.